# Alert above a NSPanel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, alert, nspanel

I have a NSPanel.
I use the following code:

```
[NSApp beginSheet:<NSPanel>
       modalForWindow:[[self view] window]
        modalDelegate:self 
       didEndSelector:nil 
          contextInfo:nil];
```

This Panel has a view that contains a NSTextField.
For some condition with NSTextField text, i need to display an Alert on top of the NSPanel View.
Code for throwing Alert:

```
NSBeginAlertSheet(@"OK", @"Cancel", nil,nil, [[self view] window], self, nil,  nil,nil, @"Error");
```

Any idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you try  NSRunAlertPanel??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.
Need to override NSControlTextEditingDelegate method with the following:

```
- (void)control:(NSControl *)control didFailToValidatePartialString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(NSString *)error

{
       NSBeginAlertSheet(@"OK", @"Cancel", nil,nil, <NSPanel instance>, self, nil,  nil,nil, @"Error");

}
```

:) :)